# Problem with my table

Tags: tables

This is my code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}



\begin{document}

 \begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Tabel over forkortelser}
\label{tab:forkort}
    \centering
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
 \begin{tabular}{ll}
    \toprule
Original form & Forkortelse    &    
    \midrule
Cross-laminated-timber & CLT &
Bygningsreglement 18 & BR18 &
Eurocodes & EC &  
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}




\end{document}
```

Why does it compile weird and with errors?

Comment: You declare 2 columns but use more than that. To overcome this, replace the & at the end of every line with \\

Comment: As leandriss mentions, each row in the table needs to be ended by ``\\``

Answer (score 3):

As correctly mentioned in the comments, you need to add `\\` after each line to declare the end of that line. I modified your code so that it compiles and works properly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Tabel over forkortelser}
\label{tab:forkort}
\centering
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\toprule
Original form & Forkortelse \\   
\midrule
Cross-laminated-timber & CLT \\
Bygningsreglement 18 & BR18 \\
Eurocodes & EC \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```